# U2U CAML Query Builder shows null for Form Library where there is value

Tags: infopath

I have a situation here and hope to hear SharePoint experts out there to help me on this situation.

I have a InfoPath form that I publish to SharePoint 2007. It contain multiple fields including a special field called "RateMe". It is a drop down with 5 values.

When select the value in the field and save the form, the value can be shown and recall from the Infopath form.

However, when I use the U2U CAML Query Builder to check the value, the value is shown "(Null)"

Appreciate any advises given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I notice that SharePoint have added a '0' behind all my fields header. Suppose a header named 'RateMe', by default, U2U CAML Query Builder will display as 'ows_RateMe', however, I notice 'ows_RateMe0' instead of 'ows_RateMe'.

I have rename the field and re-publish the Infopath form into the SharePoint and it is now working ok.